# Add drop down to PyCharm Python Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-plugin

I would like my PyCharm Python Run Configuration to have a special drop down. The content of the dropdown is populated by introspecting on my code.

I looked at the implementation of PythonRunConfiguration in the source and found no extension point to add more parameters.

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/ced3e2d03ccaa0e10aafe697323134bcd1411209/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/run/PythonRunConfiguration.java

Do I have to implement MyOwnPythonRunConfiguration then reimplement MyOwnPythonRunConfigurationEditor + factory...?

Are there extension points within IntelliJ and PyCharm to add more fields to an existing RunConfiguration via a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an implementation of the [PythonRunConfigurationExtension](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/run/PythonRunConfigurationExtension.java) interface to add a tab to the Python run configuration editor and to patch the command line started by the run configuration.

Comment: Do you know of an example plugin that uses it? I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: I don't. It's used in PyCharm itself, but the implementations are part of PyCharm Professional and therefore not open-source.